# Somehow identify celery workers that are shutting down gracefully

Tags: python, celery

I have three Celery workers as follows, each running on a different ECS node:

- **Producer**: Keeps generating & sending tasks to the consumer worker. Each task is expected to take several minutes to compute and has a database record.
- **Consumer**: Receives computation tasks and immediately starts execution.
- **Watchdog**: Periodically inspects database records, finds out computation tasks that are executing, and then does `celery inspect active` to verify whether there is actually a worker carrying out the computation.

We ensured that when the Consumer node is being terminated, the Celery worker on it will begin graceful shutdown, so that the ongoing computation can finish normally. Because Celery will unregister a gracefully stopping worker, **the consumer will become invisible to the Watchdog**, who will mistakenly think a computation task has mysteriously lost... even though the Consumer is still working on the task.

Is it possible to let a Celery worker broadcast an "I am dying" message upon receiving a warm shutdown signal? Or even better, can we somehow let the Watchdog worker still see shutting workers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Nodes in Celery cluster I am responsible for are doing something similar. Here is a snippet:

```
@worker_shutdown.connect
def handle_worker_shutdown(**kwargs):
    _handle_worker_shutdown(app, _LOGGER, **kwargs)


@worker_ready.connect
def handle_worker_ready(**kwargs):
    _handle_worker_ready(app, _LOGGER, **kwargs)
```

There are few other, very useful [signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html) that you should have a look, but these two are essential. Maybe the [worker_shutting_down](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-shutting-down) is more suitable for your use-case...

Comment: Hmmmbut the `worker_shutdown ` signal is emitted **right before** the worker is about to shutdown, which is **after** the current task has finished. But while it is still working on the current task (because of graceful shutdown), the worker is already invisible to others, hence the problem that the Watchdog mistakenly thought the worker was lost....

Comment: As I mentioned, there are other signals that you man want to check... I updated the answer with something that could be better for your use-case.

Comment: Thx~ but I am afraid that doesn't suit the purpose either.. I've tried `worker_shutting_down ` and `worker_shutdown`, and none is emitted when the graceful shutdown beings, i.e., when the celery `MainProcess` warns `Got shutdown from remote`. Still can't find a good enough signal :(.

Comment: Idk, I am sending shutdown signals to workers constantly and signal handlers work...

Comment: When the signals got captured, was your Celery worker still running an ongoing task? If there wasn't any ongoing task **and** Celery is not performing a graceful shutdown, the shutdown signal is sent almost immediately. But during graceful shutdown, if say a currently running task would take 10 minutes, then the worker won't shutdown until that task has finished. In which case the signal won't be sent in the next 10 mins (as far as I observed)~~